# Postman sending integers in body request?

Tags: json, postman

In postman, form-urlencoded, all my values are sent as strings (The value is sent as "22" instead of 22). How do I send the value as an integer?

Comment: x-www-form-urlencoded will always be string values

Comment: I have to pass integers with raw then?

Comment: Yes, but another option is to send it as a string and convert it to integer on your backend.